# How to implement select trim(string,','); for MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select trim(',hi,test,',',');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

I want to trim by `,` but seems not supported by **MySQL**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Check the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)...

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM ',hi,test,')
```